# Folder is empty but contains 4GB for 1 item?

Tags: macos, git, osx-el-capitan

I have a folder that contains no items, but `du -hs ~/dev/random-assets` says it has `3.7G`.

Get info says "3.96GB" for 1 item.

I do have git initialized on this directory.

How do I clear out the directory so it accurately reflects the files inside of it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls -al ~/dev/random-assets
```

will probably tell you that you still have a `.git` subdirectory.  If you truly wish to delete it all,

```
cd ~/dev/random-assets
rm -Rf .git
```

If you would like to be able to see dotfiles in your Finder windows instead of having them hidden, issue

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

Comment: I showed hidden files, then noticed inside the `.git` folder it had an `objects` folder containing the 4gb. I deleted that. Will that cause any harm?

Comment: @evan, the `.git` folder (together with all its subfolders) contains your git repository.  This does no harm if you are no longer interested in that repository.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some files or folders hidden in this folder and are beginning with a dot, so that's why they are hidden. If you remove the folder and recreate it you should be fine.